# boost:spirit::qi and tab as delimeter

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I'm newbie in boost. I have string delimeted with tab ( '\t' ).
How can i parse it with boost::spirit?

[parser code from boost's samples](http://dumpz.org/101260/)

Comment: So, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost sample code isn't the same as the actual boost sample, which was comma delimited, so presumably there are your modifications?

The ascii::space parser will handle the tabs for you as delimiters, so something like:

```
start %=
    lit("employee")
    >> '{'
    >>  int_ >>
    >>  quoted_string >>
    >>  quoted_string >>
    >>  double_
    >>  '}'
    ;
```

Should work (minus the '`lit('\t')`').  But, this will also parse other spacing characters (e.g. space, tab).

If you actually need there to explicitly be single tabs ONLY between the terms, then leave in the `lit('\t')` and wrap it in a `lexeme[]` to disable skipping by the skip parser.